# Consuming a PHP WSDL in .NET. WSDL 1.1 errors?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the following WSDL from a 3rd party.

http://soap-test.secureapi.com.au/wsdl/API-1.1.wsdl

Using Visual Studio 2012, I try to add a service reference and I end up with no discomap/proxy. I tried using the legacy "Add Service Reference" wizard and I get a proxy with the following type of errors

```
// CODEGEN: The operation binding 'Authenticate' from namespace 'http://soap-test.secureapi.com.au/API-1.1' was ignored.  The SOAP 1.1 encoding style is not supported for operations that use SOAP 1.2. Use the URI 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding' to refer to the SOAP 1.2 encoding style.
```

I see the same exact output when I run wsdl.exe using these parameters:

C:\Windows\system32>WSDL.exe /language:CS /namespace:SyraSvc /out:c:\test.cs fil
e://c:\API-1.1.wsdl

I tried removing the encodingStyle attribute with no improvement (encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"). I also tried converting it to a WSDL 2.0 format using XMLSpy to no avail. Any help in making this WSDL importable by Visual Studio is much appreciated.

Comment: I manually changed "encoded" to "literal" and it will import, however all web method response variables are NULL. I checked and in fiddler the web service is returning a valid response. How do I determine why in code the response is null?

Comment: did you have any joy with this? currently trying to do the same thing (right down to the 3rd party)